# hector slam on kinetic help

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
can i install hector slam on ros kinetic? if yes how  please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237510/hector-slam-on-kinetic-help/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can!
It is available for kinetic now.

---

Originally posted by [RoSPlebb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27287/rosplebb/) with karma: 64 on 2016-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1